# LED clock animation with HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm creating a dot LED-ish clock using HTML5 CANVAS. I have a problem with animation of second dots. When the code below run, the script reads the current time, takes the number of seconds and draws a respective number of dots. While seconds go, it should be draw new dots and when the next minute is started, it should clear all the second dots drawn before, but instead the same pattern of dots is drawn and the number of them was already read on the start. Can anybody know how to repair the animation?

[Here's how the second dots animation should look like.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L2pOdk6yjs)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script async="" src="tex2.js"></script>
        <canvas id="clock" width="1200" height="675" style="background-color: #000000">
            Your browser doesn't support CANVAS tag.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
/*eslint-env browser*/
/*jslint browser:true */

var clock = document.getElementById("clock"),
    face = clock.getContext("2d"),
    height = 1200,
    width = 675,
    marg = 80,
    dotRadius = 8,
    faceRadius = (width - marg) / 2,
    angle,
    i,
    x,
    y,
    time = new Date(),
    secs = time.getSeconds();
function drawFace() {
    'use strict';
    face.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    for (i = 0; i <= secs; i = i + 1) {
        angle = i * (Math.PI / 30) + Math.PI * -0.5;
        x = Math.cos(angle) * faceRadius + height / 2;
        y = Math.sin(angle) * faceRadius + width / 2;
        face.beginPath();
        face.arc(x, y, dotRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        face.fill();
        face.closePath();
    }
    face.fill();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFace);
}
function drawAll() {
    'use strict';
    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFace);
    drawFace();
}

drawAll();
```

Comment: Your never updating the variables, particularly secs, you initialize at the very start.

Comment: `time = new Date(), secs = time.getSeconds();` does not keep updating

Comment: Now it works! Thank you!